# Restaurant review site in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm totally new to SharePoint but my company has adopted it for internal use. As a learning exercise I thought it would be fun to create a local restaurant review site. Can anyone point me to an example or tutorial to get me started?

What I have in mind is a simple site where users can enter the restaurant name, cuisine style, address, a simple 5 point rating and price scale, and a short review. Other users could search for restaurants by cuisine and add their own reviews.

We have SharePoint 2007 and MOSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of *one* tutorial which will help you, but I can try to break this down for you and link to tutorials:

- Create a Web Application
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262668.aspx
- Create a Site Collection in that Web Application 
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263165.aspx
- Create a Content Type which represents 'a restaurant' 
  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA100997781033.aspx 
  What if a Content Type? In SharePoint, if Pages were object instances, then Content Types would be Class definitions.

  - You might want to create custom fields (or Site Columns) for your Content Type, such as "cuisine style." If the content type is like a Class definition, then these are like instance variables. 
    http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA101577691033.aspx
- You then need to create a Publishing Page Layout for that Content Type. The Page Layout is a template used to render a list item of a particular Content Type as HTML. 
  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/ha101741281033.aspx

  - You may need to read some about Master Pages and Content Place Holders to get this. 
    http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/ha101651201033.aspx 
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa660698.aspx
- You may need to add your Page layout to the Pages library. This should tell SharePoint to make 'Restaurant' Page Layouts available when you're creating a page. 
  http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepointtechnology/HA101106061033.aspx
- Now try creating a page representing a Restaurant! 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa660698.aspx

(sadly as I am a new user I cannot post real links :'( sorry)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look into this package from Microsoft: [Application Templates for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx). It isn't exactly about restaurants, but you can learn what do you need to make one, by studying this templates.

> Application templates are out-of-the-box custom scenarios tailored to address the needs and requirements of specific business processes or sets of tasks in organizations of any size. They also provide a starting point for partners and developers looking to build deeper SharePoint-based solutions. The templates make use of Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 capabilities and are compatible with Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007 to help make customization easier.